# How do you use HtmlToPlainText() method from org.jsoup.examples

Tags: jsoup

Mind you I've only been programming in java for one week now on a crash course so be gentle. I'm writing a program to take an online news article and all reader comments and converting them to a graphml document and I've been getting the hang of java and jsoup but now I'm trying to convert the comments to lightly formatted plain-text with the lines

```
Elements comments = qaDoc.select("li[data-comment-id]");

for (Element comment : comments) {

//code

  commentText = comment.select("div[class$=d2-body]").first().HtmlToPlainText();

//code

}
```

but I keep getting "error: cannot find symbol" pointing to .HtmlToPlainText() when I try to compile

I've put

import java.lang.Object;
import org.jsoup.examples.HtmlToPlainText;

at the beginning of my class along with other imports necessary
also I can't find the source for HtmlToPlainText it's not in the Cookbook as ListLinks is
by the way not using eclipse ide yet just the je editor and command prompt in windows
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HtmlToPlainText` is a class in the JSoup library, and the "*method*" you try to call is it's constructor, thus you will not be able to compile and run the code you have so far.

Since your code is incomplete, I assume that `commentText` is a simple String-representation of the comment, and you should then be able to do the following to achieve what you want:

```
commentText = comment.select("div[class$=d2-body]").first().text();
```

which will return a string with the text and all it's children.

You can also use the simple `toString()`-method.

```
commentText = comment.select("div[class$=d2-body]").first().toString();
```

I strongly recommend to always consult the [JSoup API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/), it can help you out a lot. In the 'examples'-subpackage you can find the class `HtmlToPlainText`.

Comment: I was using .text(); but that loses the line breaks and paragraph breaks, tabs, etc. HtmlToPlainText has method getPlainText(Element element) but that also gives the cannot find symbol error. I wouldn't mind seeing the source code for HtmlToPlainText. I don't knoe how to get it from the jsoup-1.7.2-sources.jar

Comment: When it comes to the symbol errors, I mostly think that you are trying to use classes and methods in ways they cannot be used. Since you are using Eclipse, you should use the auto-completion feature to see what methods are available to apply on a specific object instead of trying random code-chunks you've picked up in the examples.

Comment: oops HtmlToPlainText formatter = new HtmlToPlainText(); commentText = formatter.getPlainText(comment.select("div[class$=d2-body]").first());

Comment: ojected oriented is well not used to it functional languages more so like output = f(g(h(input))) math background you know